# getResourceAsStream always returning null (Google App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

I am having a bit of a problem with my code and that it always throws `NullPointerException`:

```
public class WhateverResource extends ServerResource {
    @Get("json")
    public Representation represent(){
        InputStream is =  getContext().getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/whatever.properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(is); // NPE here!
            String whatever = props.getProperty("whatever_key");
            setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
        }
        return new StringRepresentation(props.toString());
    }
}
```

I've check the genererated WAR file and in the target folder there is that `properties` file under `WEB-INF` folder. What could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to do this:

```
    InputStream is =  getContext().getClass().getResourceAsStream("/whatever.properties");
```

And GAE can read the stream without problems.

Without the `getClassLoader()`

Answer (score 1):

Put the properties in the java source folder (src) in eclipse it will be automatically copied to class folder. Then application can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Found different behavior for ClassLoader implementation on App Engine. In class, say, MyClass, Case 1 returns null whereas Case 2 returns non-null stream for a filePath( from war/WEB-INF/classes folder):

**Case 1:**

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream1 = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("filePath");
```

**Case 2:**

```
InputStream inputStream2 = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("filePath");
```

So, prefer using case 2.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, On **Google App Engine**, preferably, use **FileInputStream** class to read any file inside deployment directory, say war or target:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("propFileName")){
            if (inputStream != null) {
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.load(inputStream);
            //go ahead and code further
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle exception
        }
```

**Note:** FileInputStream Class allows you to read any file under root(WAR Folder) whereas ClassLoader.getResource(...) or ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(...) will allow you to read only files under ClassPath root i.e. under source build output folder, generally, "classes" folder in war/WEB-INF directory or similar deployment target folder.